# Sending a automated email with Power Shell's Job Scheduler

Tags: shell, powershell, email, scheduled-tasks

I am am attempting to send an automated email with the Register-ScheduledJob command. I have been able to send emails from the command line with the email.ps1 script below. I have also been able to use the Register-ScheduledJob command to create automated tasks. However, when I combine the two to make a script to send automated emails nothing happens.

email.ps1
Works

```
$receiver = "user@myCompany.org"

$sender = "name@myCompany.org"

$server = "secure.emailsrvr.com"

$subject = "Hello Mars"


 Send-MailMessage -to $receiver -credential $myCreds  -from $sender -smtpServer $server -Subject $subject
```

email_job.ps1

Does Not Work

```
 $trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "9:40 AM"

 Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Email_script" -ScriptBlock{Send-MailMessage -to "user@myCompany.org" -from "name@myCompany.org" -Subject "hello" -smtpServer "secure.emailsrvr.com" -credential $myCreds} ` -Trigger $trigger
```

Thanks

Comment: "nothing happens" <= no job created? no schedule created? no logs? Also there looks to be a rogue back-tick character in your code... is that intentional?

Comment: Where would the scheduled job get $myCreds from?

Comment: @gvee, a job is created but I do not receive an email, and there are system logs but they are not clear, let me edit the question to include some output. The back tick close to to the end  before -Trigger is intentional from an example, let me verify its use

Comment: @EBGreen, the $myCreds is a system variable which was put there using the Get-Credential command

Comment: Pretty sure jobs run in their own instance

Comment: Yep, just tested it and the jobs are running in their own instance so they would not see $myCreds

Comment: Hi,@EBGreen, you got the emails to send with the scheduled job? How did you do it?